# Cannot do "make eclipse-project" in an exsisting ROS package

Tags: eclipse, ros

When I create a new ROS package using:

```
$ roscreate-pkg test std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

and then I proceed to it, typing:

```
$ make eclipse-project
```

Everything is OK.

But when I `roscd` into an existing ROS package and type the above command, it returns :

> make: *** No rule to make target `eclipse-project'.  Stop.

Is it because the package isn't created by `roscreate-pkg`?

Answer (score 0):

did you follow the steps here ? [Ros Wiki on IDSs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs)

Comment: Yes. Now I'm using catkin. So I tried 2.2 and 2.3. 2.2 didm't work at all. I don't understand in what folder I shall generate .project ? As for 2.3, I installed all the necessary packages including wstools, but when I call "catkin build...", it always returned "catkin:command not found". :(

Answer (score 0):

I know the cause for `make` having no rule is when the rule isn't found in a Makefile.

I was having the same problem with my project and found that it had no Makefile.

Your question gave me the insight to run `roscreate-pkg` and voilà that folder had a Makefile.  The entire contents are:

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

I was able to solve the same problem by having a Makefile in my project with the same content. I did it by copying the Makefile from the dummy project I created via the following commands:

```
$ roscreate-pkg dummy std_msgs rospy roscpp

$ cp src/dummy/Makefile src/my-package/Makefile
```